# Does Distinct() preserve always take the first element in the list

Tags: c#, linq

Would

```
int[] nums = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10 };
var distinct = nums.Distinct();
```

always return `2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 10` in that order?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The defined behavior of Enumerable.Distinct is that it will return an unordered collection ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)).

However the current implementation of Distinct in Linq to Objects will preserve order.  This is not guaranteed for other LINQ providers though and the behavior should not be relied upon.

Comment: So it will sometimes return `{3, 2, 4, 10, 6, 7, 1}` (for example) sometimes instead of in the order in which the items was encountered? Do you perhaps have any links for this or an example code perhaps?

Comment: Similar answer for Queryable.Distinct ( it returns an unordered sequence ) see [DISTINCT() and ORDERBY issue](//stackoverflow.com/a/12429107)

Answer (score 3):

I think the word "unordered" means the same order of the original sequence.
Hence, the caller should decide whether to sort the result or not.

Comment: You think the word "unordered" means "in a specific order"? That is a strange thing to think! :-)  "Unordered" means "in no particular order".

Comment: @Eric: I hope you read this comment. What I mean is (and I think implied), the order of the return value sequence is not modified (i.e. order of the returned sequence is maintained as that of sequence passed in). Where have I said "unordered" means in a specific order? Hence, as per above case `int[] nums = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10 };`, the returned sequence won't sort the return value & will return `2,3,4,1,6, 7, 10`.

Comment: And that order -- the order in which the original sequence appears -- is a specific order, one out of the millions of possible orders. The documentation of the method does not guarantee that this specific order is the one chosen. In *practice* this specific order is chosen. But by "unordered" the documentation means that *any order* can be chosen by the implementation. Sometimes it is more efficient to not preserve the original order.

Answer (score 0):

In general: **no**, but in your case (with an int array): probably yes. I bet they are just enumerating the collection and disregarding items they've already come across. But don't count on that behavior across different versions of .NET or for different types of collections.

As JaredPar pointed out in his answer, the result is specified as **unordered**. If you want some specific ordering, you need to sort them afterward using whatever algorithm makes sense in your case.